# WP-CLI PHP Deprecated Warning

Tags: php, mysql, wp-cli

Under *WordPress 6.3*, *PHP 8.2*, *MySQL 8.0.34*, *WP-CLI 2.8.1*, for `wp` command like this:

```
wp post list --post__in=mypostid
```

I have this warning:

```
Deprecated: Creation of dynamic property Post_Command::$fetcher is deprecated in phar:
///home/mydomain/public_html/wp/vendor/wp-cli/entity-command/src/Post_Command.php on line 40
```

With *PHP 8.1* and *PHP 8.0*, the warning changes to:

```
WARNING: MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
```

What's happening here?

Comment: I would suggest creating a WP-CLI  issue on github.com: https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues

Comment: upgrade to the latest version of WP-CLI - it fixes some PHP 8.x deprecation notices